# ODBC Error "invalid Transaction State"

Tags: odbc

I am using odbc 3.0 with Informix and I receive the error "Invalid Transaction State" when attempting to sqldisconnect.  The beginwork and commit/rollback are in a while loop and all the tranactions work as desired (data is saved correctly); I just get the disconnect error.  What is funny is that, if I do one commit/rollback outside the while loop, the data is still saved as desired but I do not get this error.  It appears that doing a fetch on the data when there are no rows left is what is causing the issue.

Any ideas or thoughts?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Maybe you have a Cursor that is still open? I had a similar issue, which - if I remember right - was caused because I did not explicitly call SQLCloseCursor() on all Statements that were open.

Comment: If I do a single commit/rollback after reading/updating all the records, it will close.  I do a commit/rollback after each fetch so when there is no more data and I attempt to close, I will get the error. It seems that the last fetch to get to the EOD is somehow puting the handle back into transaction, even theough the last thing I did was a commit/rollback, not a beginwork.

Comment: I guess you enabled Manual Commit Mode, not? Even with Manual Commit on, every operation can potentially start a new transaction. From the doc: "Instead, a transaction begins implicitly whenever the application starts operating on the database." ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713870%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ).
So, I could think, that when you do your last Fetch the driver implicitly starts a new transaction to simply return the SQL_NO_DATA result then.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have set "connection.setAutoCommit(false);"

In this case make sure you commit/rollback all the changes before  the connection is being closed.